# Ambiguous behaviour of pandas aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, data-wrangling

So I was using pandas for some analysis and ran into a scenario, in which I had to run 2 functions for different groups in my data. And I decided to use pandas' .agg function.

Below are my 2 functions:

```
def pick_pacf(df,alpha=0.05,nlags=192):
    '''
    This function returns the lags in the timeseries which are highly correlated with the original timeseries
    Input
    1. df: pandas series, this is the column for which we are trying to find AR lag
    2. metric: str, what metric to be calculated - acf/pacf
    3. alpha: float, confidence interval
    4. nlags: int, the no. of lags to be tested

    Return
    1. lags: list, this contain the list of all the lags (# of timestamps) that are highly correlated
    '''
    

    values,conf_int = pacf(df.values,alpha=alpha,nlags=nlags)

    lags = []
    #in the pacf function, confidence interval is centered around pacf values
    #we need them to be centered around 0, this will produce the intervals we see in the graph
    conf_int_cntrd = [value[0] - value[1] for value in zip(conf_int,values)]
    for obs_index, obs in enumerate(zip(conf_int_cntrd,values)):
        if obs[1] >= obs[0][1]: #obs[0][1] contains the high value of the conf int
            lags.append(obs_index)
        elif obs[1] <= obs[0][0]: #obs[0][0] contains the low value of the conf_int
            lags.append(obs_index)
    lags.remove(0) #removing the 0 lag for auto-corr with itself
    return lags 


def pick_acf(df,nlags=192):
    '''
    This funciton takes returns the ACF value for a MA model for a time series

    Input
    1. df: pandas series, this is the series for which we want to find ACF value
    2. nlags: the number of lags to be taken into consideration for ACF

    Returns
    1. q: numpy array, The lags value at which ACF cuts off
    '''
    acf_values = acf(df.values)
    acf_values = np.round(acf_values,1)
    q = np.where(acf_values == 0)[0]
    return q
```

No need to go through the functions line by line (you can if you want to) but the main thing to focus here is what the two functions return. pick_pacf returns a list, whereas pick_acf returns a numpy array.

The calls to these functions are like this:

```
pacf_values = train_ads[['INVERTER_ID','PER_TS_YIELD']].groupby('INVERTER_ID').agg(lambda x: pick_pacf(x))
acf_values = train_ads[['INVERTER_ID','PER_TS_YIELD']].groupby('INVERTER_ID').agg(lambda x: pick_acf(x))
```

PER_TS_YIELD is a numeric column and INVERTER_ID is an alphanumeric column.

The ambiguous behaviour here is that when I call the pick_pacf function then only the pandas series of PER_TS_YIELD column is sent as input to the function for each INVERTER_ID.

Whereas, when I call the pick_acf function then first the pandas series of PER_TS_YIELD column is sent and then the whole data frame made up of INVERTER_ID and PER_TS_YIELD columns is sent to the function. This leads to an error as I am doing some calculation which error out when an alphanumeric column is received.

Why is this happening? Does the behaviour of the .agg function depends on what is being returned from the user defined function??

Can someone please explain this to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be, there seems to be some code whereby the return could be the output of `pandas.core.aggregate.aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)` or of `df.apply(func, axis=axis, args=args, **kwargs)`. To really track it, a tiny bit of data would help, or you could use `sys.settrace` yourself :)

Comment: what does `sys.settrace` do? I have looked at the variables closely in debugger mode.

I can provide you with the data for you to reproduce this. Would you like that? If yes, would google drive work?